# Qual é a diferença entre caderno e caderneta?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, diminutivos

Qual é a diferença entre caderno e caderneta?

No *Google tradutor* os dois são mesma coisa, e no *Google imagens* a caderneta parece um carderno pequeno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Caderno:

> é/
>
> substantivo masculino
>
> 3. p.ext. gráf conjunto de folhas de papel em branco ou com pautas, quadrículas etc., reunidas e encasadas, ger. grampeadas, costuradas ou
>      presas com espiral, para anotações, desenhos, colagens, exercícios
>      escolares etc.
> 4. p.ext. bibl edit gráf conjunto ordenado de páginas impressas numa única ou em várias folhas, ou conjunto similar de páginas em branco
>      que constitui cada uma das unidades ou seções reunidas e presas de
>      modo a formar um único volume.
> 5. gráf jor cada uma das partes separadas que constituem um exemplar de jornal, formada por certo número de folhas dobradas e encasadas.
>      "c. de esportes"
>
> Origem ⊙ ETIM lat. quaternus, sing. do distributivo lat. quaterni 'de
>   quatro em quatro', através do adj. erud. arc. quaderno 'quádruplo'

via google, 14 Maio 2018: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=caderno+significado

### Caderneta:

> ê/
>
> substantivo feminino
>
> 1. pequeno caderno em que se anotam ou escrevem lembretes e informações diversas. "c. de telefones"
> 2. mil pequeno caderno em que se registram o serviço, desempenho, comportamento etc. dos militares, ao longo da carreira.
> 3. pequeno caderno em que são registrados a frequência, pontualidade, comportamento e por vezes as notas de um aluno.
> 4. com econ pequeno caderno ou livro, em que é feito o registro das movimentações de uma conta num estabelecimento comercial ou
>      financeiro.
>
> Origem ⊙ ETIM caderno + -eta \ê\ (sufixo de diminutivo)

via google, 14 Maio 2018: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=caderneta+significado

### Conclusão:

Caderno: aquilo que se usa (principalmente nas escolas) para fazer anotações; feito de papel reciclado ou não, encadernado em espiral, grampo, ou laços; notebook, notizbuch.

Caderneta: pequeno caderno, geralmente encadernado em laços ou grampos, que usa para fazer registros constantes visualmente similares. Talvez na escola tivesses uma caderneta para anotar presenças, faltas e atrasos; ou tenhas hoje no trabalho.

Diminutivo de caderno: caderninho (caderneta é morfologicamente plausível, porém extremamente inadequado por ter significado próprio já).

Comment: William, deverias indicar a fonte das tuas citações.

Comment: Direto do dicionário Google, não sei muito o que deveria citar. 'Dicionário online', 'Google'?

Comment: *Dicionário Google* ou como o Google se apresentar, com hyperlink. Se não souberes com se faz, copia o endereço web para a resposta ou um comentário, que eu faço, e ficas a ver como é.Preciso do endereço, porque não consigo encontrar a tua citação online.

Comment: @Jacinto caderno: https://www.google.com.br/search?ei=fqz4WuXbKYOJwgS0rJaQDA&q=caderno+significado&oq=caderno+&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.35i39k1j0i67k1l8j0.1391.1391.0.2004.1.1.0.0.0.0.115.115.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.113....0.sovCQIaXeRI                         como aparece no navegador: https://imgur.com/a/mjyOHsY

Comment: caderneta: https://www.google.com.br/search?ei=gaz4WtTaJoOdwATvyYCIAg&q=caderneta&oq=caderneta&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0l9.79579.79883.0.80477.3.3.0.0.0.0.130.362.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.359....0.v9e8LZCFme4              como aparece no navegador: https://imgur.com/a/1ObN8gu

Comment: Quando clico no link (google...) não vejo o dicionário; deve ser diferentes configurações regionais do google; isso significa que mesmo que incluas esse link, muitos utilizadores não conseguirão ver o texto; eu aconselharia a usares outro dicionário, por exemplo o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/caderno). Para incluíres o link, a maneira mais fácil, é no topo da caixa da resposta clicas no 3º ícone a contar da esquerda (os dois elos da corrente); aparece uma outra caixinha, fazes copy e paste do endereço para essa caixinha, e depois escreves o texto que vai aparecer na resposta, p. ex Aulete

Comment: @Jacinto, a mim aparece-me. Adicionei os links da pesquisa, mais limpos.

Comment: @ANeves, na minha não; eu clico e aparece uma página de resultados do Google Search, mas sem esse dicionário.